# Lorentz transformation of Interaction therm in Weinberg book

Tags: special-relativity, field-theory, inertial-frames, lorentz-symmetry

In Weinberg book *The quantum theory of fields* he says that one  condition for the $S$ matrix to  be Lorentz invariant invariant is that the interactions therm takes the  form

$$V(t)=\int dx^3H(x,t)$$

Such that $H(x,t)$ transform as a scalar under Lorentz transformation.

But under the lorentz transfrom $$
x' = \frac{x - ut}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{u^{2}}{c^{2}}}}, \quad t' = \frac{t - \frac{u}{c^{2}}x}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{u^{2}}{c^{2}}}} .
$$
Since $H(x,t)$ is a scalar and $dx'=\gamma dx$ we have 
$$V'(t)=\gamma V(t)$$

where $$\gamma =\sqrt{1 - \frac{u^{2}}{c^{2}}}$$ 
But  $V(t)$ should transform as the $0$ component of a momentum four vector that is , take the four vector $p=(p^0.p^1,p^2,p^3)$ with $p^0=V(t)$ we should have

$$V'(t)=\gamma V(t) -\gamma \frac{u}{c^{2}}p^1$$

My question is why we have $V'(t)=\gamma V(t)$?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the S matrix is written like
$$
S=\langle f|{\cal T}\exp\left(-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int dt'V(t')\right)|i\rangle
$$
being $\cal T$ the time-ordering operator. This makes the integration with respect to time Lorentz-invariant.

Comment: What i am asking is why $V(t)$ does not transform as energy

Comment: In this case $p_1=0$, as you have $p_{\mu}=(V(t),0,0,0)$. This particular choice makes the trick.

Comment: Why should we have  $p_1=0$ ?

Comment: Because you are in the rest frame. Note that, if you are not, the $S-$matrix will grant you to be there because you are just an unitary transformation away.